# Using jQuery plugins in SPFx web part

Tags: jquery, spfx, sharepoint-framework

I'm looking for a reliable way to implement jQuery plugins into my SPFx web part (targeting SharePoint 2016 on-prem). I have jQuery installed with `npm install` and imported with `import * as jQuery from 'jquery';`. I want to use a couple of plugins like [Bootstrap Wizard](http://vinceg.github.io/twitter-bootstrap-wizard/), [jQuery steps](http://www.jquery-steps.com/) or [Form Validator](https://www.npmjs.com/package/jquery-form-validator).

When I install a plugin with:

`npm install --save <plugin> @types/<plugin>`

`require('<plugin>')`

it doesn't throw any errors, but when I'm trying to use one of the jQuery functions from the plugin, it's not recognized as part of jQuery.

I also tried loading the plugin with `SPComponentLoader`, after serving the project with gulp, I can run jQuery functions in the browser console, but still not in IDE.

- What is the recommended way to use jQuery plugins in SPFx web part?
- How can I integrate plugins that are not by default supported on npm?

Answer (score 0):

I found [this article](https://medium.com/@NetanelBasal/typescript-integrate-jquery-plugin-in-your-project-e28c6887d8dc) very helpful.